# Creating a symlinked asset folder in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am wondering if it is at all possible to create and use a symlinked assets folder in SilverStripe.

I am deploying with capistrano and wanted to make use of the `linked_dirs` setting whereby Capistrano creates moves the assets folder outside the silverstripe release directory to a `shared` directory.

Is it possible to hook up SilverStripe to this directory without a great deal of 'hacking' around. What else do I need to consider?

Comment: it is possible! what is the limitation you hit?

one thing to watch out, is to use the same version of PHP on CLI as with HTTP otherwise you'll end up with files in silverstripe-cache that errors about memorylimit...

and in _ss_environment.php you should use realpath for the current linked version
`$_FILE_TO_URL_MAPPING[realpath('/home/user/project/current/')] = 'http://domain.tdl/';`

Comment: Okay cool, I haven't run into the issue yet. I remembered reading a post an old post on the SS forums about this a couple of weeks ago that warned off the idea, can't seem to find it now. So I can just symlink the assets folder and silverstripe will act as normal, only populating files into the shared folder above the SS directory? I apologise if that is a dumb question, I'm primarily a front end dev.

Comment: I use it that way but you can check it on your environment with moving assets-folder somewhere else and creating a symlink like `ln -s /what/ever/path/to/assets ./assets`

Comment: Yep, all working as expected! Thanks for your help understanding this. If you copy one of your comments into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for the score: yes it just works.

In the comments above, you can find some information around the topic :)